# How to initialize an array when using a template

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I created an array template for my personal use.

```
template <typename T, int size>
struct Vector {
    T data[size];
};
```

I tried to intialize the data like so:

```
Vector<unsigned char, 10> test;
test.data[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

My compiler ended up complaining something about "expected expression."  Does anyone know what I'm doing?  I want to be able to use this style of initialization where you give it the entire array definition at once instead of using a for loop to init the elements individually.

Comment: Unless you plan on adding more things to that struct, I think you would be better off using plain old arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your class is an aggregate, you can initialize it with the usual brace syntax:

```
Vector<int, 3> x = { { 1, 2, 3 } };
```

The exact same thing applies to `std::array<int, 3>`.

Answer (score 2):

In the new standard, C++11, you can use `std::initalizer_list` to get the desired result, see the below example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T, int size>
struct Vector {
  T data[size];

  Vector<T, size> (std::initializer_list<T> _data) {
    std::copy (_data.begin (), _data.end (), data);
  }
  // ...

  Vector<T, size>& operator= (std::initializer_list<T> const& _data) {
    std::copy (_data.begin (), _data.end (), data);
    return *this;
  } 
};

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Vector<int, 10> v ({1,2,3,4,5,6}); // std::initializer_list

  v = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0}; // operator=
}
```

---

If you are working with a standard prior to C++11 it's a bit more of a hassle really, and your best bet is to implement functions similar to those available when using `std::vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T, int size>
struct Vector {
  T _data[size];

  Vector (T* begin, T* end) {
    std::copy (begin, end, _data);
  }   

  // ...

  void assign (T* begin, T* end) {
    std::copy (begin, end, _data);
  }   
};  

int 
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{   
  int A1[4] = {1,2,3,4};
  int A2[5] = {99,88,77,66,55};

  Vector<int, 10> v1 (A1, A1+4);

  // ...

  v1.assign (A2, A2+5);
}
```

Comment: Your first example won't compile.

Comment: @jrok I see nothing wrong with the snippet, care to enlighten me?

Comment: GCC says: "error: assigning to an array from an initializer list" for last line in first snippet.

Comment: @jrok ah, right.. I had a vague memory of assignment from std::initializer_list to T[] made it into c++11, but I guess it was only a c++0x gcc draft implementation. Snippet changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can only *initialize* an array at the point you are *defining* it:

```
Vector<unsigned char, 10> test;
```

There's your array, you are done defining it, your chance to initialize it has passed.

**Edit:** Seeing Mat's answer, memo to me: I **have** to read up on C++11, and soon... :-/

**Edit 2:** I just gave the information on what was wrong. Kerrek SB has the information on how to do it right. ;-)

Comment: I think I was wrong, and you are correct - that syntax is for initialization only...

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply the type and size of the array when defining the variable:

```
Vector<int, 10> test;
```

You can not however assign to the member array like a normal array. You have to assign each element separately:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    test.data[i] = i;  // If instantiated with type "int"
```

Comment: "You can not however assign to the member array like a normal array."  Not true anymore in C++11.